# Background image path is not working even when I use url('../../images/image.png')

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am getting `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` error when I give the background image path as shown:

```
body {
    background-image: url('../../images/img.png') !important;
    background-color: #d0dfe5 !important;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    font-size: 14px !important;
}
```

I don't for what reason I am getting this error. Is there anything I need to change in the path?
Please help me.

Comment: What does your directory structure look like?

Comment: MyProject->WebContent->images->image.png

Comment: I was expecting a picture that shows where the css and image is, so I can see how the css will access the image (in terms of url)

Comment: I have edited my question by adding image

Comment: There is no image with name image.png in your images folder :/

Comment: I have changed it to image.png here. The actual name og my image is hrm_taustakuvan_verkko.png

Comment: @ miqdadamirali Please help me.

Comment: try this '../images/hrm_taustakuvan_verkko.png'

Comment: It is working. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @ miqdadamirali Please answer my question so that i can accept :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your directory structure, your image is in a folder one level above current location and not two. Which is why you need to use `../` as suppose to `../../`

Try this: `'../images/hrm_taustakuvan_verkko.png'`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the path in your css

```
background-image: url('../../images/image.png') !important;
```

You are in "`personaltitania/WebContent/styles/personaltitania_base.css`", and the image files are in "`WebContent/images/`", but you return two levels when you use "`../../`", in this moment you try found the image "image.png" in "`personaltitania/images`".

Try using

```
background-image: url('../images/image.png') !important;
```

And, I don't see in your images folder the file "image.png"

Answer (score -1):

show screenshot  on your files

### Heading ##`.bg{

```
background: url('../img/banner3.jpg') no-repeat 60% 90%;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: 100% 100%;
position: fixed;
width:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
```

}`
[my files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwaCw.png)